# WINSOCK , TCP : No connection between two computers

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, ip, winsock

I'm not able to connect to a TCP server on a computer from a client in another computer on the same local network. I'm Getting an error 10060.
I'm able to connect to the server if the client is launched on the same computer as the server.

Here's some info about the server, then the client
(client running on .30 , server = .50)

[TCP info of client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPjmg.jpg)

Here we can see that my client is sending a SYN signal to the correct IP/PORT

[TCP info of Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0XG7.jpg)

The server seems to be listening to any IP and port. So it sounds like I'm not understanding how to set up setsockopt.

Here's the main() of the server that doesnt work if the client isn't on the same computer:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // Start of experiment
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;

/* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
    {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    //int option = 1;
    bool option = TRUE;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
  pthread_t tid;

  /* Socket settings */
  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  /* Ignore pipe signals */
    //signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); Sigpipe doesnt exist in NT. I need to implement something ...

    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &option, sizeof(option)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR: setsockopt failed\n");
        printf("Error : %i\n",WSAGetLastError());
        printf("port was: %i\n",port);
        printf("Ip Was : %lu\n",serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
        WSACleanup();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Bind */
  if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket binding failed");
    WSACleanup();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  /* Listen */
  if (listen(listenfd, 10) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket listening failed");
    WSACleanup();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    while(1){
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        /* Check if max clients is reached */
        if((cli_count + 1) == MAX_CLIENTS){
            printf("Max clients reached. Rejected: ");
            print_client_addr(cli_addr);
            printf(":%d\n", cli_addr.sin_port);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
        }

        /* Client settings */
        client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));
        cli->address = cli_addr;
        cli->sockfd = connfd;
        cli->uid = uid++;

        /* Add client to the queue and fork thread */
        queue_add(cli);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);

        /* Reduce CPU usage */
        sleep(1);
    }
    WSACleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I somehow managed to make it work when messing around parameters, but I'm not able to reproduce it since I don't understand how winsock works yet.
I tried to disable Firewall on both computers, but it didn't help.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Have you considered looking Winsock error 10060? But your server is only listening to 127.0.0.1. Use INADDR_ANY.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I can now establish a connection. I'm so sorry I was pretty sure I already tried it ... By the way I can't find how to accept your comment as an answer. I'm only used to browse Stack Overflow, not using it !